# Why is my simple bash script is not running?

Tags: bash-scripting, centos-6

I am just writing a simple Bash script on CentOS 6.2:

```
[root@hadoop1 ~]# vi bash_startup

#! /bin/bash
export r=1
```

Backing to the command line:
and running using ./bash_startup

```
[root@hadoop1 ~]# echo $r

[root@hadoop1 ~]#
```

echo `$r` gives me no result, why?

Comment: What happens in your script if you change `! /bin/bash` (which is incorrect) to `#!/bin/bash` which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to environment variables in a script only affect the calling shell if you call the script like:

```
. ./script.sh
```

Or:

```
source ./script.sh
```

Not:

```
bash ./script.sh
```

Or:

```
./script.sh
```

This is because the former two ways run the script in the current shell, while the latter two start a subshell, and environment variable changes aren't propagated upward out of subshells.

Comment: What about that `! /bin/bash`. Shouldn’t it be a `#!/bin/bash`? What you say is right, but it seems like this script has a few issues.

Comment: @JakeGould While that is indeed wrong as well, I don't think it's relevant to the problem OP is asking about.

Comment: Quite relevant. `! /bin/bash` will run `bash` and negate its exit status. This new shell may be indistinguishable from the old (sourcing) one at the first glance. The OP may think everything has been sourced and try `echo $r`; it will return an empty line, as if your solution changed nothing. `export r=1` will be sourced in the old shell only after exiting the new shell.

Comment: I am running using ./bash_startuo and corected the bin bash file but still I dont get value for 'r'

Comment: @Mat The answer explicitly says you should source the file, not run it.

Comment: what do you mean from sourcing? running using 'bash ./bash_startup' also gives me no output.

Comment: You tried the exact two commands that I said won't work.